# Excel Macro to change font in cell

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need a macro that will in my spreadsheet search for:

1. In Colum B: find a cell that contains "H1 or H2 or H3 or H4"
2. then when found, change the font to bold and underline in the text in Column A

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Have a look at conditional formatting, there is no VBA needed: [Use conditional formatting to highlight information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f): As formula for conditional formatting you could use `=OR(B1="H1",B1="H2",B1="H3",B1="H4")` on cell `A1` and apply to it to column A then

Answer (score -1):

There are syntax mistakes, but I think the structure is something like this.

```vb
Dim I as Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 0 to LastRow
  If Cells(I, 2).Value = "H2" OR If Cells(I, 2).Value = "H3" Then 
    Cells(I, 2).Font.Bold = True 'Probably doesnt work search the syntax 
  End If
Next I
```

Comment: Can you review the indentation? It wasn't indented, which made it hard to follow. Also, your first variable declaration was hidden due to it being on the same line as your opening code block; I fixed this for you. I believe the `Next` should also be indented, but it's been a while since I've looked at VB, so you'll want to review.

Comment: This code has several issues. Here are some of them: 1) You're finding the last non-empty cell in column A and using that as the last non-empty cell in column B. 2) `LastRow` is (quite rightly) a `Long`. However `I` (which is also being used as a row number) isn't. 3) Not an issue per se, but you don't need `.Value =` simply `Cells(I, 2) =`.